# Difference between -x+y=3 and -4x+4y=12 lines equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I would like to know whats the difference between these two lines. My question is what it means to multiplicate the line equation by 4, what does it change? My professor said it has something to do with the ´line speed´

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: It means that every "solution" of the first equation is a solution of the second, and vice-versa.

Comment: What is a "solution"? a pair of values for $x,y$ that satisfies the equation. Example: $1$ and $4$.

Comment: In terms of analytic geometry, this meas that they are satisfied by the same set of points.

Comment: Yes, but the multiplication must have some effect on the line or it does not?

Comment: If they are "spatially" different, there is some point laying on one line that does not lay on the other one. Can you find one?

Comment: @ToklCz, multiplication of the equation does nothing to the the line, unless you multiply by $0$. Same like adding the same number to both sides of the equation does nothing to the line it represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
&l_1 \ldots\ -x+y = 3,\tag{1}\\
&l_2\ldots\ -4x+4y = 12\tag{2}.
\end{align}
Now, let point $(x_0,y_0)$ lie on the line $l_1$. Then, it satisfies the equation $(1)$, which means that $-x_0+y_0 = 3$. Multiplying by $4$ we get $-4x_0 + 4y_0 = 12,$ so the point $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfies the equation $(2)$ and therefore it lies on the line $l_2$. So, every point on $l_1$ also lies on $l_2$.

Conversely, let point $(x_0,y_0)$ lie on the line $l_2$. Then, it satisfies the equation $(2)$, which means that $-4x_0+4y_0 = 12$. Dividing by $4$ we get $-x_0 + y_0 = 3,$ so the point $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfies the equation $(1)$ and therefore it lies on the line $l_1$. So, every point on $l_2$ also lies on $l_1$.

We conclude that the lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ consist of the same points, that is $l_1 = l_2$.

---

So, what does multiplying of the equation by $4$ do to the line? Absolutely nothing. The "line speed" your teacher is talking about probably refers to parametrizations of the lines. For example, all points of the form $(t,t+3),\ t\in\mathbb R$, lie on the line $l_1$, and all the points that lie on $l_1$ are of that form. Of course, the same goes for $l_2$, since $l_2 = l_1$. Now, we can also look at all the points of the form $(4t,4t+3),\ t\in\mathbb R$. It turns out it's again the same set of points, but you can think of this second parametrization as "going faster" since if we think of $t$ as representing time, the first parametrization takes us from $(0,3)$ to $(1,4)$ in one unit time, while the second parametrization in one unit time takes us from $(0,3)$ to $(4,7)$, so the second parametrization describes "faster traversing of the same line".

However, these different parametrizations both satisfy both of the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, and there is no canonical way to attach one parametrization to one equation and the other parametrization to the other equation, so in my opinion, multiplying by $4$ that occurs when manipulating the equations and multiplying by $4$ that occurs with the parametrizations don't have any connection with each other, besides using the fact that the function $t\mapsto 4t$ is a bijection on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes i get this, does that mean that the multiplication does nothing?

Comment: @ToklCz They're not the same equations, but they have the same solutions. Multiplying by $4$ "does something" to the equation, but nothing that will affect the line you end up plotting. It's a subtle distinction: the equation (the string of symbols in either side of an $=$ sign) has changed, but if we only care about the solutions, then nothing important has changed.

Comment: @ToklCz, I edited the answer.